# Eclipse checkstyle and formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

There is confusion .

For my project i created my own `Formatter` and `checkstyle` .

**example:-Formatter**

there is a `Brace` tag in Formatter so i made two changes.

Brace Position:-

*Class/interface ..NextLine*

*Constructor Declaration ..Next line*

after write some code i am not following formatted rules .

Then why my `checkstyle` not showing any message like `"Brace should be next line"`.

Currently i am using my own style and previous using `Sun Checks(eclipse)-global`

Answer (score 1):

Checkstyle and formatter are two different things. Your formatter can help in respecting the rules you've defined in your checkstyle configuration, but your checkstyle configuration does not use the formatter to define its rules.

I do not remember what the "Sun Checks(eclipse)-global" set of rules defines in terms of white spaces around the left curly brace, but whatever the case you might want to define your own rules.

- Right-click on your project, select "Properties"
- Got to "Checkstyle" then open the "Local Check Configurations" tab
- Hit "New...", leave the combo on "Internal Configuration" and type a name (say "Sample"), hit "OK"
- Go back to the "Main" tab, and select "Sample - (Local)" in the combo, hit "configure..."

This is where you configure your own customized set of checkstyle rules. For example in order to make a rule that will mark an error in your editor if the "left curly brace" is on the same line as its block's signature instead of being on a new line :

- expand "Blocks"
- double-click "Left curly brace placement"
- select "eol" to force the curly brace to be at the end of the line and hit "OK"
- hit "OK" again to go back to the main window of your project's properties
- make sure that the "checkstyle active for this project" checkbox is ticked

You can configure a lot of custom rules for your project, see [checkstyle's documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) for help.

**[edit** : a thought after I wrote this ... maybe the fact that you do not see a warning with the "Sun checks(eclipse)" basic configuration comes from the last point I outlined above : make sure that the "checkstyle active for this project" checkbox is ticked in your project's properties **]**